# Update password in ldap using java

Tags: java, ldap, spring-ldap

I am using spring `ldapcontextsource` + java to interact with AD. When I create the user account with a new password, everything works fine. Code is below

```
context.setAttributeValue("unicodePwd", AD.getUnicodePwd(persona.getPassword()));
```

However, when I tried to update the using password with the same code above, I got the following error:

```
  [LDAP: error code 20 - 0000207E: AtrErr: DSID-031906FC, #1: 0: 0000207E: DSID-031906FC, problem 1006 (ATT_OR_VALUE_EXISTS), data 0, Att 9005a (unicodePwd) ]; nested exception is javax.naming.directory.AttributeInUseException: [LDAP: error code 20 - 0000207E: AtrErr: DSID-031906FC, #1: 0: 0000207E: DSID-031906FC, problem 1006 (ATT_OR_VALUE_EXISTS), data 0, Att 9005a (unicodePwd) ]; remaining name 'CN=brian_2 brian_2,OU=Test Group,OU=Organization Users,OU=ICE Accounts,DC=vetasi,DC=stage'
```

In addition, I have tried following the code. userpassword is set successfully, but I can not log in by using a new password and the old password still works

```
context.setAttributeValue("userPassword", persona.getPassword());
```

at the very end, I used the below code to modify the context

```
ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(context);
```

Comment: to update password you need to use // Perform the update
     ctx.modifyAttributes(theUserName, mods);

Comment: @dassum i updated my post. yes, i used  ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(context); at very end.

Comment: @brian were you able to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
ModificationItem item = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute(passwordKey, ("\""+password+"\"").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE)));
                ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(name, new ModificationItem[]{item});
```